# Does beer really go bad after the 'best before'-date?

Tags: taste, health, preservation

Does beer really go bad after the 'best before'-date?

I hear I can drink beer even after the expiration date, but is it safe and does it still taste good?

Comment: I drank 3 years old beer without any major change in taste. It was extra strong so I got tipsy too. Nothing happened. So, I do not think this may cause any adverse health issue. But it should be consumed within 6 months of the date of its manufacturing for best results.

Comment: I tried some bottles of best-before-2010 Belgian beer the other week... it was awful. It smelled OK, but just tasted yuk.

Comment: If you are shopping at places where you consistently see beer on shelves after their best by date then its safe to assume that they aren't putting as much care into their stock. When i see that it starts to make my choices at that store change. I no longer trust the beer that they have will taste like it should. Forget trying to buy any IPAs as they lose their hop aromas, and will only consider beers where their age isn't as important such as higher alcohol beers, stouts, porters, brown ales, etc

Comment: I'm about to drink a can of purchased in 211 Guinness beer. On the can is written best before 3.06.2012. Wil it be good for drinking?

Comment: I drank a left over beer from the can which was kept after opening for a fortnight.Except some change in the taste like somewhat flat I find there was no other problem

Comment: Coopers beers in Australia have a "Best After" date instead of "Best Before" http://imgur.com/znngsoj

Comment: Me and my brothers ate army rations from the 1950.s in the the 1970,s mostly tined and dried foods and they were fine cake chocolate meat biscuits fruit cocktail still in fantastic condition we should all remember there where no expiry dates before the 70,s lol we used our nose taste and eye's sell by dates were invented by the manufacturer,s to sell more of there products by scaring people into thinking OMG its out of date through it away just remember those army rations packs we ate were at least 20 year's old its best before not bad after

Comment: I have drank a beer that was 5 years old and it just tasted a bit stronger, but didn't really have any negative health effects because of it.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The beer will not be bad in the sense of unsafe to drink, since no harmful pathogens grow once the beer is fully fermented. So you can certainly drink the beer.

However, the beer may not taste good! Over time, the beer will oxidize, both from oxygen introduced during packaging, but also through the release of oxygen from compounds previously oxidized in the beer. The oxygen causes the beer to stale, producing tones of sherry, paper, cardboard. Hop aromas are muted, and hop beta acids oxidize to produce an unrefined bitterness. Other forms of staling can lead to a soap taste.

Generally, the higher the alcohol content of the beer the less you need to be concerned with the use by date.

Comment: Oxidation is bad in beer but often desired in wine.

Answer (score 11):

StillTasty.com has the following to say with regards to beer - particularly specifying that this applies to regular or light beer from bottles or cans manufactured by major breweries:

**[Opened Containers](http://stilltasty.com/fooditems/index/16511)**

Good for 1 day, refrigerated.

> Tips:
>
> - Keep refrigerated and tightly covered.
> - After opening, most commercially manufactured beer will remain safe to consume if properly stored, but it will quickly become flat and lose flavor.

**[Unopened Containers](http://stilltasty.com/fooditems/index/16512)**

Good for 4-6 months, in pantry or refrigerator.

> Tips:
>
> - The precise answer to the question "How long does beer last?" depends to a large extent on storage conditions - store beer in cool, dark area.
> - Keep beer away from direct sources of heat or light; too much exposure to light can cause beer to develop a foul taste.
> - To maximize the shelf life of beer, store beer at a temperature between 45° F and 55° F (colder than the typical room temperature, but warmer than a refrigerator) - if this is not possible, store beer in the refrigerator.
> - Storage times shown are for best quality only - after that, the beer's color or flavor may change, but in most cases, it will still be safe to consume if it has been stored properly.
> - How to tell if beer is bad? If beer develops an off odor, flavor or appearance, it should be discarded for quality purposes.
> - "Best By," "Best if Used By," and "Use By" dates on commercially packaged foods sold in the United States represent the manufacturer's estimate of how long the product will remain at peak quality - in most cases, the beer will still be safe to consume after that date, as long as it has been stored properly and the package is not damaged.
> - Beer made by some micro-breweries may not retain peak quality as long as beer from major breweries.

Comment: You should never discard beer for "quality purposes". Just keep it until you are tanked up and can't taste it anyway.

Answer (score 4):

This depends entirely on the beer. As a rule of thumb I would say that any beer which is re-fermented once bottled, can be preserved for several years. You need to be careful when preserving, but it's not unheard of to drink 35 year old beers. Often these beers are the darker, stronger ones like Westmalle or Orval.

Answer (score 3):

It should still be safe, taste good is a personal opinion.

Some beers age well, high alcohol, sours, and smoke beers. Others don't age as well (hoppy beers). Plus it all depends on how the beer was stored. Out in a hot garage? Sitting in your window sill?